# Having several qdisc for each device, which is the first to process?

Tags: embedded, tc, qos, traffic

I have read about queuing disciplines here http://lartc.org/. Having this traffic shaping policy:

```
....
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev ppp0 root bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev ppp2 root bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Assuming that there is only outgoing traffic in band 0 of ppp0 qdisc and band 2 of ppp2 qdisc, which is dequeued first? I understand that band 0 is prioritized over band 2 within same qdisc, but is band 0 of ppp0 qdisc prioritized over band 2 of ppp2 qdisc?.

Answer (score 1):

Queuing disciplines are per-device. There is no prioritizing between devices, they can send frames in parallel.

Comment: So what happen with several interfaces using the same device? For instance ppp1, ppp2 using same ADSL line.